# How to uninstall MariaDB 5.5 completely (including configurations) from CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, centos7

I tried command

```
yum remove mariadb mariadb-server
```

It removed the client but failed to remove the server.

```
error reading information on service mysql: No such file or directory
error: %preun(MariaDB-server-5.5.41-1.el7.centos.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package MariaDB-server-5.5.41-1.el7.centos.x86_64
error: MariaDB-server-5.5.41-1.el7.centos.x86_64: erase failed
Erasing    : MariaDB-client-5.5.41-1.el7.centos.x86_64                                                                                        1/2 
Verifying  : MariaDB-client-5.5.41-1.el7.centos.x86_64                                                                                        1/2 
Verifying  : MariaDB-server-5.5.41-1.el7.centos.x86_64                                                                                        2/2 

Removed:
MariaDB-client.x86_64 0:5.5.41-1.el7.centos                                                                                                       

Failed:
MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:5.5.41-1.el7.centos
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, let's do some research -- there are several likely places for stuff to be left behind:  the main directory:  `.../mysql/...`; the config: probably `/etc/my.cnf`; and wherever CentOS start up daemons: maybe `/etc/rc*/*mysql*`; `/.../bin/*mysql*`.  Also, check for *mariadb*.  Let us know if you find something left behind.

Comment: SO is for programming related questions only. From the SO help pages: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com)."

Comment: Posted the same question in [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/1024192/how-to-uninstall-mariadb-5-5-completely-including-configurations-from-centos-7)
Let's see what we get from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reinstalled MariaDB and then uninstalled using **rmp** not yum. Below are the steps I performed-

**Downloaded the required RPMs**

```
wget http://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-5.5.41/yum/centos7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-5.5.41-centos7_0-x86_64-client.rpm
wget http://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-5.5.41/yum/centos7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-5.5.41-centos7_0-x86_64-common.rpm
wget http://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-5.5.41/yum/centos7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-5.5.41-centos7_0-x86_64-server.rpm
```

**Install it again**

```
rpm -ivh MariaDB-5.5.41-*.rpm
```

**Erase packages**

```
rpm -e `rpm -qa | grep MariaDB` --noscripts
```

**Remove the config files**

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
rm /etc/my.cnf
```

Comment: thanks for documenting your steps NS